# Eclipse (CDT): include a subdirectory, exclude it from any build

Tags: eclipse, project, eclipse-cdt, subdirectory

What is the proper way to include a newly created subdirectory into the project, but exclude its content from building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If folder you created is inside your project tree than, click on your project in `ProjectExplorer` view and than simple <kbd>F5</kbd> will refresh yor project content.

If folder you created is outside your project tree, than right-click on your project in `ProjectExplorer` view and than `New`→`Folder`→`Advanced`→`Link to Alternate Location`→ browse for your folder.

To exclude folder from build right-click on your new folder in `ProjectExplorer` view and than you can find the option under `Recource Configuration`→`Exclude from Build...`.

Folder should go gray after excluding.